# Redux store not updating by action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have setup a reducer in redux to to manage state. I am calling that reducer through an action creator. The action is dispatching (coz I hava subscribed to the store and put a console.log there)

This is what the reducer looks like

```
import C from "../constants"
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export const wishlist = (state = [], action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case C.REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_WISHLIST:

      return state.filter(product => product.ProductName !== action.payload.ProductName)

    default:
      return state
  }

}

export default combineReducers({
  wishlist

})
```

Like I said, I have hooked it up with an action creator which I know is firing (again, coz the store is subscribing)

This is what the action creator looks like

```
import C from './constants'


export const removeProductFromWishlist = function(ProductName) {
    return {
        type: C.REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_WISHLIST,
        payload: ProductName
    }

}
```

Is there something I am missing here?

for reference, here is the `initialState.json`

```
{
    "wishlist": [

    ],
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `action.payload` is the ProductName, not an object containing a `ProductName` key

Comment: where is your `product` object?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was missing. Can't believe I spent so much time trying to find the bug. Thank you so much, @bowheart

Is there a way I can mark your answer as correct?